# How to resolve a menu issue with HTML5 responsive design website that has superfish and dynamic load of header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, superfish

I have a responsive design site using HTML5, CSS, Superfish menu and mobile-menu div.

Everything works well when the Header and footer content is static in every page.

However, When I do a

```
$('.header').load("myheader.html");
```

in my js file documentready, the menu loads and looks fine in a non mobile browser.  But in a mobile browser it's not there.

Has anyone else run into this? Has any suggestions as to how to resolve it?

Comment: If you provide the HTML and CSS you are using for the menu (or a jsfiddle) it may be easier to detect the problem.

Comment: I haven't had time to do this.  My guess is the timing of the load of the html is the issue.  I need a way to reapply the css to the page once the load() has finished.  is there a listener event for that?

Comment: the CSS should work for the entire page... unless your menu is loading an iframe or is enclosed in a container as a different page. I.e. if you receive new HTML through a template, the CSS also applies to that HTML, but the Javascript triggers (onclick, onhover, etc.) must be reloaded.

Comment: the $('.header').load("myheader.html"); above is inside my JS file upon the Document ready of that page.  so My question becomes.. do I need to force something to apply css or what not to that content once loaded ?

Comment: CSS is applied to whatever content you load: if the browser finds the matched elements, the rules will be applied to them (unless your mobile browser works differently). What I think is happening is that there is some JS error triggered only in the mobile browser, you can test if this is the case by modify something in the page after the load function: if nothing is modified, the load has some problem.